# how to post variables to aspx page and push a button with php

Tags: php, curl, post

I just want to fill a form in aspx page via php. is it possible? I tried some Curl codes but didnt work. Thanks for the answers.

```
$url = 'somepage.aspx';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
$data['button_name'] = "button_value";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

$output=@curl_exec($ch);
$info = @curl_getinfo($ch);

if(curl_errno($ch)){
  echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}

curl_close($ch);
echo "output is:'" . $output . "'";
echo "<br>";
echo "info is:";
print_r($info);
```

Comment: What output do you get from that? I suspect you'll need to provide an absolute URL to cURL.

Comment: You can't `push a button` with PHP, only client side code can do that.  You can submit to the forms action url, with the post values though.

Comment: It is possible but a little more complicated than the code shown due to the nature of the tokens and other hidden fields that you need to capture. Either generate a statically compiled list of the various hidden field names or use an initial curl request to simply GET the page and process it to find the names and values of these elements. Those details should then be used in the subsequent POST request

Comment: I actually get nothing, just the echo. cant push the button and fill the form in the page with the code.

Comment: Try something like Goutte https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte